# How to segregate dumped points?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am new to PostGIS. I have some linestring geometry values. Each linestring contains multiple points. I have dumped the points from that geometry by ST_DumpPoints. By ST_AsText, I have found that the first linestring contains 10 point sets (x,y,z) then second linestring contains 4 point sets. Now, I want to create a column named start and another column named end. The start will contain the start point of each point set of the linestring and end point will contain the next point of the point set of the linestring without the z value. E.g.

```
linestring1 dumped points: (1,2,2),(2,5,4),(3,4,5)......
linestring2 dumped points: (1,3,2),(3,3,4),(4,5,6)....
```

Now source and End columns will be

```
Source     End
(1,2)      (2,5)
(2,5)      (3,4)
(3,4)      .
.          .
.          .
.          .
.          .
(1,3)      (3,3) 
(3,3)      (4,5)
(4,5)      .
.          .
.          .
.          .
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following query to dump the points, retrieve their order number (`nr`), drop the Z value with `ST_Force2D` and then left join them to the next one:

```
WITH 
a AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS id, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING( 1 2 2, 2 5 4, 3 4 5)') geom
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS id, ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING( 1 3 2, 3 3 4, 4 5 6)') geom
)
, c AS
(
  SELECT
    b.id,
    (b.dump).path[1] nr,
    ST_Force2D((b.dump).geom) geom
  FROM
  (
    SELECT
      id,
      ST_DumpPoints(geom) dump
    FROM
      a
  ) b
)
SELECT
  c.id id,
  c.nr nr,
  ST_AsText(c.geom) geom,
  c_next.nr next_nr,
  ST_AsText(c_next.geom) next_geom
FROM
  c
LEFT JOIN
  c AS c_next ON c.id = c_next.id AND c.nr + 1 = c_next.nr;
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you correctly you want to use [ST_StartPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.4/ST_StartPoint.html) and [ST_EndPoint](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_EndPoint.html).  To drop the z value use [ST_Force_2D](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Force_2D.html).

To break the line into segments (which it sounds from your comment that this is what you want to do), see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174472/in-postgis-how-to-split-linestrings-into-their-individual-segments).

Comment: The start point is giving the first point but end is giving the last point set, but I need each point

Comment: I think he wants to get individual segments. Please have a look at my answer. I hope it answers the question.

Comment: Yeah - I think you're right.  I see that now.