# equivalent Explode lines in Postgis

Tags: postgis, explode

I want to divide linestring into separate segments via Postgis, like it "Explode lines" tool in QGIS does, e.g. from linestring 
I want to get separate segments
[image]

I have some thoughts about take it by using (st_dumppoints(Linestring)).geom then split linestring by their nodes with ST_split and dump again received geometry collection, but I got an unexpected result, because it returns me segments like 
[image]
(not pair of coordinates as I expected!)

Maybe anybody have some ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has been solved in a [number](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174472/in-postgis-how-to-split-linestrings-into-their-individual-segments) of [posts](https://www.mail-archive.com/postgis-users@postgis.refractions.net/msg02883.html). Here's the one from Paul Ramsey that I like the best: http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/breaking-linestring-into-segments.html

It boils down to:

```
 WITH segments AS (
SELECT gid, ST_AsText(ST_MakeLine(lag((pt).geom, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY gid ORDER BY gid, (pt).path), (pt).geom)) AS geom
  FROM (SELECT gid, ST_DumpPoints(geom) AS pt FROM lines) as dumps
)
SELECT * FROM segments WHERE geom IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code in the other answer doesn't work for me, it gives some duplicate segments, but I might have done some mistakes.
The following code is taken from the [same page](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/02/breaking-linestring-into-segments.html) and works for me:

```
SELECT st_makeLine(p0,p1)
FROM (
  SELECT st_pointN(way, generate_series(1, st_nPoints(way)-1)) p0,
  st_pointN(way, generate_series(2, st_nPoints(way)  )) p1
  FROM osm_line
) AS pts
```

Comment: Did not work for me, the singlepart geometries had more than two nodes.  I leave this comment as a warning to others.